# 32-bit nasm assembly not starting on 64 bit system

Tags: 32bit-64bit, nasm, ld

I have written a 32-bit assembly file and I want to compile it ( and have it working) on a 64-bit Linux system. I have installed `gcc-multilib` and `lib32-glibc`.

I try to create the binary with the following commands:

```
nasm -f elf test.asm
ld -melf_i386 -o test -e _main test.o /usr/lib32/libc.so.6
```

where `_main` is the entry point. The file test is created, and I chmod it:

```
chmod ugo+x ./test
```

Howevery, I am unable to open it. I get:

```
bash: ./test: No such file or directory
```

I am certain the file exists, because I can open it in vim (and I can see ELF written on the first line). What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The message has to do with the dynamic linker, because using dynamic libraries require some more effort. The easy way is to link to the static C library (/usr/lib32/libc.a). But if you just call your entry point "main" and link it like a normal C program (gcc -m32 -o test test.o) it will work too.

Answer (score -1):

Problem in not in the compiler.

Actually your typing a wrong command.

1)for compiling a 32 bit program command is : nasm -f elf32 test.asm

```
    and for 64 bit asm or assembly language file command is : nasm -f elf64 test.asm
```

2) after compilation you need to link that file for that command is :

```
     ld -o test test.o  ( for both the 64/32 bit program)
```

3)and now u will be able to execute the program by using the command :

```
      ./test
```